# Can I use string interpolation in a Twilio verb?

Tags: ruby, twilio, twilio-twiml

When I receive a call, I output the `CallSid` parameter and save it as a variable `@incoming_Cid` to track the call throughout it's duration and manipulate it.

When I try to bridge the call in between a customer and an employee, I dial a conference. I'd like to use the `@incoming_Cid` as the friendly name to make the conference unique every time.

Example:

> `puts params['CallSid']`
>
> `@incoming_Cid = params['CallSid']`
>
> `Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|`
>
> `r.Dial :action => '/greeting/handle-gather/techsupp/conference', :method => 'get' do |d|`
>
> > `d.Say 'Please wait while we connect you to one of our operators. '`
> >
> > `d.Conference "#{incoming_Cid}"`
>
> `end`
>
> `end`

Normally, I have the friendly name in ' ', but string interpolation requires " ". So I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is correct/allowed?

Also, how can I output the `sid` params of a dialed conference like described [here.](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/conference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are definitely going in the right direction here.
There are a few suggestions I would make to accomplish what you are going for. Here is my modified snippet:

```
puts params['CallSid']

@incoming_Cid = params['CallSid']

response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
  r.Dial :action => '/greeting/handle-gather/techsupp/conference', :method => 'get' do |d|
    d.Say 'Please wait while we connect you to one of our operators. '
    d.Conference @incoming_Cid
  end
end
puts response.text
```

The changes I made are assigning your `TwiML::Response` to the response variable and outputting the [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) text at the end which will be your generated XML response.

I also changed your d.Conference line to simply output `@incoming_Cid` without putting it in quotes, which in this case should work as valid Ruby.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The thing is I don't need the `d.Conference` line to output `@incoming_Cid`, it should dial a conference where the friendly name is the value or string saved as `@incoming_Cid`. 

Also, how did you format the code to have the different colors and whatnot? I still haven't figured it out.